# Retreiving integer data from file in python

Tags: python

I want to make a matrix with the first 2 columns of data (from file) as 1st matrix and the third column as another matrix

the data is in the text file is like

```
2104,3,399900
1600,3,329900
2400,3,369000
1416,2,232000
3000,4,539900
1985,4,299900
```

and I want a resultant matrix as
`[2104 3], [1600,3],[2400,3], ...`

and second matrix as 
`[399900], [329900], ....`

Comment: Here's some info on reading from files - https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python

Here's some info on python lists - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm

Comment: As there is a vast number of ways to do this, please show us what you've tried so that we can help guide you. Before you do though, read through the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Comment: @ZAIN Ali You should take a look at the documentation for the csv module from the standard library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

```
filename = "path-to-filename"
list_a = []
list_b = []

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
                line = line.rstrip('\n')
                line_list = line.split(',')

                list_a.append(line_list[:2])
                list_b.append(line_list[2])

print(list_a)
print(list_b)
```